# How can I change the layout of listview's row's but my listview is already customized and dynamically created

Tags: android, listview

I have created a dynamic and customized listview which contains 2 imageview and 3 textview.what I want is that when user clicks a row so row's background color and one image should be change that is OK.But when user clicks another row so the previously clicked row (with changed image and background color) should get its previous image and background color.

So basically at once only one row's layout should be changed.
Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Cache which item in your adapter is the currently focused one, and in your adapter's overridden getView() function, set all items state to `unfocused` (normal background, etc.) and if the particular row is filled with the aforementioned item, set it to `focused`... hope this was clear.